# How to override render for C# asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working with a page and basically if my user isn't authenticated I want to show the user the HTML on the Web Form page, otherwise I want the response to be JSON and kill whatever would be on the page... does anyone have any idea of how I could do this? Can you tell me the way to get to the response before the view does?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "get to the response before the view does" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the JSON track, you could do `Response.Clear()`, `Response.Write()` your json data, then `Response.End()` to send the json and not process the standard page.